# How to create/update user on MacOS with space in AccountName

Tags: macos

I know that my question is strange and ask moderators not to delete or close this question.

I have to test one thing on different MacOS environments and also with space in AccountName. By default it is impossible and prohibited.

But on Windows it is possible. Maybe, someone know the way to create or update profile with space (for example: "new user") in this field.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because firstly it is not about programming so it is off-topic and secondly it is unreasonable to expect an OS to do something its design specifically precludes... https://serverfault.com/a/578264

Comment: No problem, if it is a rule.
I explained why it is important for me.

Comment: Sorry lad, but this is the wrong forum. Ask in Superuser as there are the people who are able to answer. StackOverflow is for codemonkeys and programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

@Vas23Vewe different operating systems have these restrictions in place for a good reason. If you for the issue it will invariably break down somewhere down the line.

If you were to attempt to rename a user with spaces and unpermitted special characters you may end up breaking paths to directories. This will cause inconsistencies when your MacOS tries to load files under your namespace.

Comment: This is the idea. A am QA tester, so I have to understand how it will affect.